# How to stop high rank members adding their own rules to the site

Tags: discussion, moderator-tools

In Graphic Design SE the moderator sent to me a message "see this discussion in GDSE Meta". [What to do with tutorial requests? -- part II](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3368/what-to-do-with-tutorial-requests-part-ii)

I wasn't the only one. The same message was sent to a couple of other GDSE users. We have the following common factor: The moderator and his supporters think that we write far too easily answers to "How do I get this result in Photoshop, Illustrator, Inkscape etc..." -type questions. He confirmed it to me in the discussion.

The number of those answers isn't small. That's because the number of those questions isn't small. They flow in faster than the moderator and his high rank supporters can close them with flagging, so most of them get answers. Some of us have earned with them 1000 points of rep/month. That's a big number and probably unachievable for many of us if we had answered only to more demanding questions.

The moderator and his supporters have taken the opinion "How to" questions are mostly low level junk and do not earn answers. Only those which are based on questioner's own attempts and some specific problem during those attempts earn to get answers. If the questioner hasn't achieved anything or keeps it hided, he should get nothing. (Request of free work gets the same treatment)

The moderator and his supporters claim that we invite "how to" questions to flood in => GDSE isn't interesting to those who are interested in more demanding things in Graphics.

I am interested as well in technical "How to" subjects as more demanding things. I believe the moderator and his high rank supporters have a plan to get more effective tools to keep "How to" questions out. Those tools would be effective against any topic and would be a serious threat to still existing pluralism.

How to stop them?

Comment: If you have concerns about how a specific site is run, you need to address it **on that site** on their meta or use the contact button to contact a CM.

Comment: Those rules sound completely reasonable and in line with other sites on the network. SE sites are not here for people to farm their work out to, the purpose is to build libraries of high quality content that can easily be found and reused by others with similar questions. That said, all of these sites are moderated by and evolve with their communities; if you want to change the direction (within the broad goals of the network) then engage on the appropriate Meta.

Comment: As others have said, this needs to be brought up on Graphic Design Meta, not here... You've *already* posted on that meta discussion though and it's very much still an ongoing discussion, which by the looks of it seems to be going in your favour, so I'm not entirely sure what the problem is here

Comment: @Cai No problem. It works also here. Of course it costs a lot of reputation, but that's not money.

Comment: No, It doesn't work here. I only see this now and it completely takes me aback and I think it is a very, very low blow.

Comment: I'm going to continue on what others have said, that it needs to be posted on GD Meta not Meta.SE. If there is a problem with a mod, SE policy is to contact them, *not* post on meta. If you have a problem with site policy, well, that goes on *that sites* meta.

Answer (score 12):

> How to stop high rank members adding their own rules to the site?

The answer to the short version of your question is to seek consensus on the per-site meta. That's exactly what it's for. Moderators are there to help the community keep to the policies that everyone has agreed on meta.

You use several times the phrase "the moderator and his supporters." It rather sounds like there is already a consensus agreed on the meta by the active community, and you personally disagree with it. Consider whether the "serious threat to still existing pluralism" might be you.

Comment: There, at this point, is no consensus on that linked meta question... actually... and two of the top answers seem to side with the OP here... so I'm not really sure what they're complaining about. :/